# Setting value of BAPI structure?

Tags: c#, structure, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

it's my first time using a BAPI and API to get data from an ABAP system, my problem is that I don't know how to send a specific entry (ORDER_OBJECTS) see below :
these are my BAPI entries :
[image]

and this is the ORDER_OBJECTS :

[image]

for now I can send the NUMBER entry, but I don't know how to send an "X" to the column 'O' (OPERATIONS) in ORDER_OBJECTS.

this is my code :

I keep getting the message :

> Element ORDER_OBJECTS[OPERATIONS] unknown

please can anyone help me solve this

thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Could you edit your question and type plain text instead of screenshot please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a `IRfcFunction` object, `SetValue` can only handle scalar/elementary parameters like `NUMBER`.

The parameter `ORDER_OBJECTS` is structured, so you should first query the `IRfcStructure` object from the `IRfcFunction` object, then apply `SetValue` on that `IRfcStructure` object :

```cs
IRfcStructure struct = readData.GetStructure("ORDER_OBJECTS");
struct.SetValue("OPERATIONS", "X");
```